# How to count the result of a if loop within foreach loop

Tags: powershell, if-statement, foreach, powershell-4.0

Is there a better way to be able to count the amounts of empty groups than using this method and then calling $count + 1 for each result? I tried to mess around with `$123.count` but it kept returning 0

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Properties * -Filter * | where { $_.Members.Count -eq 0}
$123= Foreach($G In $Groups)
{
    $Membership = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $G.Name
    If($Membership.count -eq 0){
    $Count = $count + 1
    }

}
```

Comment: `@($Groups).Count`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That would only give empty groups, but the groups can still be members of something. I want $groups to have gone through $Membership.count -eq 0

Comment: So you want to count the number of groups that have no members and are themselves not member of any groups?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Correct. I also would like to not use "$count +1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get-ADGroup can do much of what you ask without going away from AD.

Getting this done with the Filter parameter is painful. The LDAP filter however is simple.

For empty groups:

```
Get-ADGroup -LdapFilter "(!member=*)"
```

For empty groups which are also not nested inside other groups:

```
Get-ADGroup -LdapFilter "(&(!memberOf=*)(!member=*))"
```