# Get a list of users who are not part of ANY group in the active directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, extract

On the internet as well as SO, I can see solutions for finding out all the users in AD or users who are not part of some particular group/groups. But I want to have a list of users not part of ANY group(i.e. part of Domain Users only). I have a lot of AD groups and it is impractical to hard code it in the script. I also know about the CSVDE tool and have been able to extract the data out of it, but unfortunately the output is quite convoluted and not user friendly. What I am looking for is to extract this information in two columns - `User|MemberOf` in a flat file. A PowerShell solution is preferable but I am open to any solutions as long as it doesn't involve installing any third party software as it is not allowed in my organization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count the result of a if loop within foreach loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998075/how-to-count-the-result-of-a-if-loop-within-foreach-loop)

Poorly formulated question, but the answer is still relevant.

Comment: @Jakodns - what's an empty group? Does it imply having no groups? If not, then this answer is not of any relevance to me.

Comment: The only difference between the two questions is the referenced object type. Granted we wouldn't be looking at the member attribute on a user (as it is not there), but the memberOf back-link is. If the memberOf backlink is empty in either a user or a group the object does not belong to anything except the primary group. You can ask AD to return that as described by the examples I've posted in both this and the linked question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like this:

```
Get-ADUser -LdapFilter "(!memberOf=*)" -Properties memberOf | Select-Object SamAccountName, MemberOf
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This doesn't help me in any way. It neither gives a list of users "NOT" mapped to any group, nor gives data in 2 columns as mentioned in my question. Let me know if the question is not clear, I can add the specific details you want.

Comment: It returns all users who are not part of any group. I've added Select-Object to the example to generate an object that can be two columns should you wish to export it to CSV or use it in a gridview or any other technique.